# php - Check same column twice in mysqli query

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

I have 3 tables in my php based system. 
Those tables are `product`, `category`, `product_categories`.

**Product**

```
pid | product_name | price
1 | Nike T-Shirt | 23
```

**Category**

```
cid | category_name
1 | Men 
2 | Women
```

**Product_categories**

```
pcid | cid | pid
1 | 1 | 1 
2 | 2 | 1
```

That means, 1 product may be in both multiple categories.
Now I am developing the product search section with filter.
If a user select both categories, all the products in selected categories should display.

Example : If a user select both Men & Women, Nike T-Shirt should be displayed.

The query I used:

```
select p.* 
from products p 
left join product_categories pc on pc.pid=p.pid 
WHERE pc.cid ='1' AND pc.cid = '2'
```

But it not returning correct products.

Where is the error?

Comment: `WHERE pc.cid ='1' AND pc.cid = '2'` < That can't be right. You're looking for `OR` not `AND`.

Comment: Hi @FunkFortyNiner - Both cid's should match. So, I am looking for `AND`

Comment: That condition is a contradiction, it can never be true. pc.cid cannot be '1' AND  '2' at the same time.

Comment: @Jindra - Then what is the alternative?

Comment: If what @GMB writes isn't what you want maybe this is: ```select * from product where product.pid = any (select product_category.pid from product_category where cid = 1 or cid = 2);```

Comment: Your query will always returns blank.  `pc.cid= '1' AND pc.cid = '2'` will always return false.

Answer (score 0):

You want conditions that span over multiple rows, which suggests aggregation. You can join the tables, `group by` product, and use the `having` clause for filtering:

```
select p.id, p.product_name, p.price
from product p
inner join product_category pc on pc.pid = p.pid
inner join category c on c.cid = pc.cid
where c.category_name in ('Men', 'Women')
group by p.pid, p.product_name, p.price
having max(c.category_name = 'Men') = 1 and max(c.category_name = 'Women') = 1
```

If you can filter by category id rather than by category name, then you need one less join:

```
select p.id, p.product_name, p.price
from product p
inner join product_category pc on pc.pid = p.pid
where pc.cid in (1, 2)
group by p.pid, p.product_name, p.price
having max(pc.cid= 1) = 1 and max(pc.cid = 2) = 1
```

Comment: Hi @GMB, Thank you very much for your valuable time. I tried your code. But it giving me the `Warning
: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in error. ` Can't understand why.

Comment: @JohnKreeda: that's a PHP error, not a SQL error. You might want to try and run the code directly in a SQL client (phpmyadmin or the like) to test it outside your application.

Answer (score 0):

Here are few alternatives:

```sql
-- All products that are at lest in one of the desired categories
select * from product where product.pid = any (select product_category.pid from product_category where cid = 1 or cid = 2);
```

```sql
-- Products that are in both categories
select * from product where product.pid = any (
  select product_category.pid from product_category where cid = 1 or cid = 2 group by pid having count(cid) = 2
);
```

```sql
-- Products with additional information "in how many desired categories they are"
-- You can order by it and/or filter on it
with product_category_matches as (
  select pid, count(*) as category_count from product_category where cid in (1, 2) group by pid
)
select *, product_category_matches.category_count from 
product inner join product_category_matches on product.pid = product_category_matches.pid
where product_category_matches.category_count > 0 -- Product must be at least in one desired category
order by  product_category_matches.category_count desc
```